# Can't find the bug in the program to print the longest input line

Tags: c, arrays, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000

int mygetline( char line[], int maxline); /*will return length */
void copy (char to[], char from[]);

int main(){

    int len; // length of the line
    int max;  // maximum length seen so far
    char line[MAXLINE];
    char longest[MAXLINE];

    max = 0;
    while((len = mygetline(line, MAXLINE)) >0){
        if (len>max){
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }

        if (max>0){ 
            printf("%s", longest);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

/*getline: reads a line into s, and returns length of the line */
int mygetline(char s[], int limit){

    int c, i;
    for(i=0; i<limit-1 && (c=getchar())!= EOF && c!= '\n'; ++i){
        s[i] = c;
    }

    if (c=='\n'){
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }

    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

/*copy: copy 'from' into 'to'; assume to is big enough */
void copy (char to[], char from[]){

    int i=0;
    while((to[i] = from[i] != '\0')){
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Above stated is my code for printing the longest input line. Code is compiling without any errors and yet when I am running the program it is not printing anything. I can't find what is going wrong in here.

Comment: Try printing the value of "len" at the beginning of your while loop to see if it's actually getting into the loop..

Comment: `while((to[i] = from[i] != '\0')){` should be `while((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0'){`. also `if (max>0){..}` move to after while-loop.

Comment: Please indent you code properly. As it stands reading it is a pain ... :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit simpler and does the job by using the available string functions, instead of examining char by char. If you need to, you can open a file for input and replace `stdin`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000

int main(){
    int len;    // length of the line
    int max;    // maximum length seen so far
    char line[MAXLINE];
    char longest[MAXLINE];
    char *sptr;
    max = 0;
    while((sptr = fgets(line, MAXLINE, stdin)) != NULL) {
        if ((sptr = strtok(sptr, "\r\n")) != NULL) {
            len = strlen(sptr);
            if (len > max) {
                max = len;
                strcpy(longest, sptr);
            }
        }
    }
    if (max)
        printf("%d: %s\n", max, longest);
    else 
        printf("No strings read\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your braces for assignment with to and from is incorrect. Try:

`while (((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0'))`

If you try printing value to to[i] and from[i] you would find the problem in your code.